# Install hexdump in an Ubuntu Docker image

Tags: 16.04, apt, docker

I am using the `ubuntu:16.04` image, but apparently it doesn't have the `hexdump` package (because some other stuff I do in the image are failing because of it). So, I tried to `apt-get install hexdump` but got an error `E: Unable to locate package hexdump`.

When I search for info online it seems like this package should be installed with Ubuntu by default, but maybe in the Docker image it was stripped out. And thus I can't really find sources for how to install it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`hexdump` utility is part of **bsdmainutils** package.

Alternatively, you could use `xxd` from the **xxd** package

Answer (score 18):

Add the following command in the Dockerfile of the image:

```
RUN apt-get install bsdmainutils
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate docker image based on ubuntu 16.04 and copy xxd from ubuntu LTS into docker image.

The Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM amd64/ubuntu:16.04
COPY xxd /usr/bin/xxd
```